# What is an example of function $h(x, y)$ satisfying $\displaystyle\lim_{|(x, y)|\to +\infty}\frac{h(x, y) x}{|x|^p +|y|^q}=+\infty?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $1<p<q$ and consider the function
$$h(x) =\begin{cases}
|x|^{q-2} x &\text{ if } |x|\le 1\\
|x|^{p-2} x (\log|x| +1) &\text{ if } |x|> 1
\end{cases}.$$
Defined $H(x) = \int_0^x g(\tau) d\tau$, during the calculus class we proved that
$$\lim_{|x|\to +\infty}\frac{H(x)}{|x|^p}=+\infty.$$

As an exercise, starting from the above defined $h$, we have to construct a 2-variable function $h(x, y)$ satisfying
$$\lim_{|(x, y)|\to +\infty}\frac{h(x, y) x}{|x|^p +|y|^q}=+\infty$$
where $|(x, y)|$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Do you have any suggestion for that? Actually, the problem is that I don't know how to manage the powers $|x|^p +|y|^q$ at the denominator to construct the new function.

Could someone please help with that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such function $h$, because $\lim_{|y|\to+\infty}\frac{h(0,y)\times0}{0^p+|y|^p}=0.$

Comment: @geetha290krm easier than I thought, thank you!

Comment: @Lorago thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval actually I don't understand what do you mean. Why the examples carried on in the previous comments do not answer the question?

Comment: AnneBauval is right. There is no such function $h$.

Comment: @C.Bishop, you didn't understand my comment, so let me insist: $|(x,y)|$ may tend to infinity with $x$ fixed to $0$ (just take $|y|\to+\infty$).

Comment: @geetha290krm why the function you suggested does not work?

Comment: It works if you take limit as $|x|$ and $|y|$ both tend to infinity.  But you are taking limit as $|x|^{p}+|y|^{p} \to \infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm ok, I see. How it should be written the limit in that case?

Comment: Instead of $|(x,y)| \to \infty$ you should gave $|x|,|y| \to \infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for the help. What your are saying means also that if I had to consider $\frac{h(x, v)x}{|(x, y)|}$ instead of the one in the question, the limit with $|(x, y)|\to +\infty$ it would have work, right?

Comment: @C.Bishop no, the same problem would happen there as well. What you want for it to be true is that you let $\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert\to\infty$